# Shader: Mesh Renderer and Sprite Renderer are not respecting sorting order

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite, layer, depth

I have a fbx model that uses Unity's mobile unlit shader and another sprite that uses a custom shader. I have checked that they are both in the same renderer queue, however, they don't draw in respect of the sorting order but of the depth only.

When I have sorting order of the sprite renderer set to 100 and sorting order of the mesh renderer set to 0, I'm expecting to see the sprite drawn in front of the model, regardless of the depth. But that's not what I am getting.

Currently, the 3D model is using Unity's built-in mobile unlit shader (https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResourcesExtra/Mobile/Mobile-Lightmap-Unlit.shader),
and my custom sprite shader has these flags set in a SubShader block:

```
    Lighting Off
    Cull Off
    ZWrite Off
    BlendOp [_OpColor]
    Blend [_SrcFactor] [_DstFactor]
```

Please let me know if there are ways to achieve this?

Comment: Make sure all shaders are in the Transparent queue with ZTest disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by `layer of the sprite renderer`? Are you editing its `order` in its [`SortingGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html#sortgroup) or? Are you editing the [`layer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) of the object? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I created custom editors for mesh and sprite renderers in order for me to edit their sorting orders (m_SortingOrder)

Comment: If you're referring to [`this sorting order`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/SortingGroupEditor.cs), I don't believe this has any effect on 3D objects.

Comment: It's a property for mesh renderer but it has no effect on 3D meshes? There is no way to make it work by writing a custom shader?

Comment: [`Here`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/3d-object-mesh-behind-a-sprite-sorting-layer.453692/) is a better answer than I can give why this won't work or at least will not work well. I assume to expose the private field you describe in your question, you are using an implementation similar to [`this gist`](https://gist.github.com/allanolivei/8982445). I would add more code to your existing question to prompt others to understand your situation a bit better.